# Wireguard on VPS

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, wireguard

I'm a newbie at networking. I tried to configure a WireGuard VPN on my VPS. The connection to my already configured server works just fine. I can check it in VNC, but after connecting to a WireGuard server from my VPS the public IP of my VPS has become unavailable. After WireGuard connection I cannot connect to my VPS server.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use a VPN inside the VPS and connect to it via ssh or rdp afterwards,

As what a VPN does is changing the VPS IP, what is the reason of running the VPN in the VPS?
What you must do is use the VPS as a host and then use your computer as client to change your computer's IP. The other way around doesn't make much sense.